# Is it true that `inplace=True` activations in PyTorch make sense only for inference mode?

Tags: python, pytorch, activation-function

According to the discussions on `PyTorch` forum :

- [What’s the difference between nn.ReLU() and nn.ReLU(inplace=True)?](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/whats-the-difference-between-nn-relu-and-nn-relu-inplace-true/948)
- [Guidelines for when and why one should set inplace = True?](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/guidelines-for-when-and-why-one-should-set-inplace-true/50923)

The purpose of `inplace=True` is to modify the input **in place**, without allocating memory for additional tensor with the result of this operation.

This allows to be more efficient in memory usage but prohibits the possibility to make a backward pass, at least if the operation decreases the amount of information. And the backpropagation algorithm requires to have intermediate activations saved in order to  update the weights.

Can one say, that this mode, should be turned on in layers only if the model is already trained, and one doesn't want to modify it anymore?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`nn.ReLU(inplace=True)` saves memory during both **training** and **testing**.

However, there are some problems we may face when we use `nn.ReLU(iplace=True)` while calculating gradients. *Sometimes*, the original values are needed when calculating gradients. Because `inplace` destroys some of the original values, some usages may be problematic:

```
def forward(self, x):
    skip = x
    x = self.relu(x)
    x += skip # inplace addition
    # Error!
```

The above two consecutive `inplace` operations will produce an error.

However, it is fine to use **first** addition, **then** activation function with `inplace=True`:

```
def forward(self, x):
    skip = x
    x += skip # inplace addition
    x = self.relu(x)
    # No error!
```